# Typescript - Iterating through an Interface

Tags: typescript

I am a noob in working with typescript, but cannot avoid it in angular.
So, I was writing the code as I learn.

I wanted to make a function that iterates over the keys of an object and performs some small tasks. In my case, I want to iterate through the keys because interface properties are optional and all of them may not be present. Here is the relevant part of my code: -

```
interface GameState {
  gameId?: string,
  minPlayers?: number,
  currentChoiceMakingPlayer?: number,
  gameEndReason?: string,
}

export class GameManagerService {

  gameState: GameState = {};

  synchroniseGameData = (gameState: GameState) => {
    for (let key in Object.keys(gameState)) {
      let typeKey = <keyof GameState>key;
      this.updateEntryInGameState(typeKey, gameState[typeKey]);
    }
  };

  updateEntryInGameState = <GameStateKey extends keyof GameState>(key: GameStateKey, value: GameState[GameStateKey]) => {
    this.gameState[key] = value;
  };
}
```

I understand most of it, except for the actual spotlight stealer function `updateEntryInGameState` (bottom of the code).

The tutorial I used gave this brief explanation (which I'll translate with respect to parameter names in my code): -

> Adding the type variable `GameStateKey` for the `key` type allows us
> to use it for the `value` type while still ensuring that the `key` is
> a key of GameState using `extends keyof GameState`

But I still don't fully understand how this works.

Mainly, What does `<GameStateKey extends keyof GameState>` do before the function definition? And how is it being applied to the parameters of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does `<GameStateKey extends keyof GameState>` do before the function definition?

It defines a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types) *type parameter* for the arrow function being assigned to `updateEntryInGameState`.

> And how is it being applied to the parameters of the function?

Wherever you see `GameStateKey` in the rest of the function's code, it gets its type from the type parameter. When you call `updateEntryInGameState`, the type of `GameStateKey` is inferred from the type of the first argument you give the function (the one received as the `key` parameter), and the second argument's type is then defined as the type of the property that that key designates in a `GameState` object (or subtype of it). (You can also specify the type explicitly as a *type argument* on the call, `this.updateGameState<theTypeGoesHere>(/*...*/)`, but in this case there's no need.)

Basically, it lets you say that the key will be a key of `GameState`, and the value will be of the type of the property with that key in `GameState`. So during the call, if `key` is `"gameId"`, the type of `value` will be `string`; if the `key` is `"minPlayers"`, the type of `value` will be `number`.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. That was a great explanation.